# why doesn't ≈ (isapprox) work with an atol parameter in version 1.2

Tags: julia

In the Julia documentation is a [unit test example](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Test/):

```
using Test
@test π ≈ 3.14 atol=0.01
```

When I run it in Juliabox which currently has version 1.0.3 the test passes.

When I run it on my windows 10 computer with Julia version 1.2 I get:

```
Error During Test at In[25]:2
  Test threw exception
  Expression: ≈(π, 3.14, atol=0.01)
  function ≈ does not accept keyword arguments
```

`@test ≈(π, 3.14, atol=0.01)` gives the same results.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. Can you share what `methods(≈)` produces? It seems that `≈` definition from Base might be overwritten in the code you run.

Comment: Today I couldn't reproduce the error anymore. I don't know how I've overwritten the ≈ definition yesterday. But I now know how to look for the problem should it occur again. thanks!